# Redirect in Apache while preserving subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain

I have a website that is heavily made up of subdomains. I want to redirect all subdomains to their HTTPS counterpart but I'm not sure how to do that in my vhost

```
http://subdomain1.example.com/ -> https://subdomain1.example.com/
http://subdomain2.example.com/ -> https://subdomain2.example.com/
...
http://example.com/ -> https://example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code should solve your issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain1.example.com
  ...
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain1.example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: check that `mod_rewrite` is enabled

Comment: this rewrite rule is for the HTTP vhost, not for the HTTPS

Comment: I should mention the sub domains are dynamic. It's not just the two I gave as examples